# Cross-thread tab drawing

Tags: c#

Basically, I have a TabControl.
I am drawing the text for the headers myself so they can be coloured when required.
The calls to change colour are on a different thread then the one the TabControl is, so I am using delegates and such for cross-thread operations.
Unfortunatly my method is not exactly reliable.

Here is the cross-threading part:

```
delegate TabControl getTabDelegate();
private TabControl getTab()
{
    if (this.channelTabs.InvokeRequired)
    {
        getTabDelegate d = new getTabDelegate(getTab);
        this.Invoke(d);
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return channelTabs;
    }
}
```

and here is the drawing code:

```
private void channelTabs_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        TabControl ct = getTab();
        using (Brush br = new SolidBrush(TabColors[ct.TabPages[e.Index]]))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.Bounds);
            SizeF sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString(ct.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ct.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left + (e.Bounds.Width - sz.Width) / 2, e.Bounds.Top + (e.Bounds.Height - sz.Height) / 2 + 1);

            Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;
            rect.Offset(0, 1);
            rect.Inflate(0, -1);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.DarkGray, rect);
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "1");
    }
}
```

As you can see, in some cases getTab(); returns null, which isn't exactly helpful.
Is there any more...reliable method of doing this?

Here is the method that is called from the second thread to change the header colour:

```
private void SetTabHeader(TabPage page, Color color)
{
    TabColors[page] = color;
    channelTabs.Invalidate();
}
```

Without the cross-threading part, of course, I get exceptions thrown.

And as you can probably imagine, channelTabs is the GUI tab control.

Any help is apperciated, thanks!

--
Oh yea, and if it is actually helpful:
    private Dictionary TabColors = new Dictionary();

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update GUI from another thread in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

Comment: All that appears to be how to modify a property, I am trying to retrieve the control and draw to it

Comment: It's the same problem. You're modifying the GUI from a non-GUI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your drawing is going to need to be done in the UI thread anyway so what I would do is to modify `channelTabs_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)` like so:

```
channelTabs_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if(this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(() => channelTabs_DrawItem(sender,e));
        return;
    }
    TabControl ct = channelTabs;
    ...
```

which will ensure that you are always running in the right thread and avoids using the potentially dangerous call to `Invoke`.
If you really want to fix the code you are using, what you need to do is to return the value from Invoke like so:

```
private TabControl getTab()
{
    if (this.channelTabs.InvokeRequired)
    {
        getTabDelegate d = new getTabDelegate(getTab);
        return (TabControl)this.Invoke(d);
    }
    else
    {
        return channelTabs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used a similar method for other cross-thread calls as well, simpler than what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating things - You need to be using Invoke for the SetTabHeader function, *not* the drawing event or getTab. Those will only naturally be called from the UI thread as long as you don't do anything silly like call Invalidate from a different thread.

```
private void SetTabHeader(TabPage page, Color color)
{
    if(this.InvokeRequired) {
        this.Invoke(new Action<TabPage,Color>(SetTabHeader),page,color);
    } else {
        TabColors[page] = color;
        channelTabs.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is failing because of this...

```
delegate TabControl getTabDelegate(); 
private TabControl getTab() 
{ 
    if (this.channelTabs.InvokeRequired) 
    { 
        getTabDelegate d = new getTabDelegate(getTab); 
        this.Invoke(d); 
        return null; // <-- The return from your invoke is ignored
    } 
    else 
    { 
        return channelTabs; 
    } 
}
```

Instead do this:

```
delegate TabControl getTabDelegate(); 
private TabControl getTab() 
{ 
    if (this.channelTabs.InvokeRequired) 
    { 
        getTabDelegate d = new getTabDelegate(getTab); 
        return this.Invoke(d); // Don't lose the return value from the invoked call
        //return null; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        return channelTabs; 
    } 
}
```